# Angular: return data from $http function

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
$http.get("/rest/users/getUser/" + token)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                });
console.log(deferred.promise);
return deferred.promise;
```

But I always get `undefined` in console. Why and how can I fix it? BE part works fine.

Comment: How are you accessing it in your controller

Comment: @Hurix I configured routing with writing `user` object to scope like `$scope.user = AuthService.getUser()`

Comment: @Squeez Try this syntax and see whether you are getting the output or not  $scope.user = uthService.getUser().then(function(result) {
  return result ;
});